# How to get an int from the end of a string seperated by a space that might have more ints in it?

Tags: python

I'm making an "arena" pyton script where users can battle. It reads from "ArenaList.txt" and each string is formatted "username skill", like "wootiown 15" or something like that. I'm trying to find a way to get the int at the end of that string, set that to one int, get the username at the beginning and set it to an str, then be able to change the skill value in the file. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `str.split`? The following code should work (I think, your question isn't very clear):

```
def getNumber():
    data = []
    with open('ArenaList.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            name, number = line.split()
            number = int(number)
            data.append([name, number])
    return data
```

This creates a new list containing the names and skills of each player. For example, if the file contained

```
wootiown 15
testing 5
```

the above function would return

```
[['wootiown', 15], ['testing', 5]]
```

Comment: that worked great, thanks!